# Issues with uploading images

Tags: django, django-models, django-uploads

I want to upload images and they must be store in media folder.But when I upload an image it is uploaded and its name is store in database but image is not stored in media folder (even I don't know where it stored).

**settings.py** is:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/ghrix/html/media'
MEDIA_URL = 'media'
```

**models.py** is as:

```
from django.conf import settings
class Upload_files(models.Model):

    image           =models.ImageField(upload_to='/images')
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProductForm(forms.Form):
    image  = forms.FileField()
    class Meta:
        model=Upload_files
```

I don't know where I am wrong may be  I have to import something in model.So please help me...

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the leading slash on '/images' ?

Comment: Yes, I tried but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ur MEDIA_ROOT should be

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'
```

Comment: It doesn't. But it seems that file is uploaded but not stored , Because I copy the name of the file from database and search in my system, It shows only one record (the actual one), is my model wrong???

Comment: Ur file should be in the Project_Root/media/images folder and u dnt need that slash before 'images'

Comment: @rakesh......Thanks for your help.If I want to display those images then how I can do that ???